# Structured module interface for C

Tags: c, data-structures, interface, function-pointers, encapsulation

I want to improve my C code style a bit and as well encapsulate my code a bit more. Furthermore, the interface to my modules should be clear and easy to handle.

In my project I have several modules containing the different functions.

modul_1.c

```
static int modul_1_func_2(void);

void modul_1_func_1(void) { ... }
int modul_1_func_2(void) { ... }
void modul_1_func_3(int) { ... }
```

modul_1.h

```
void modul_1_func_1(void);
void modul_1_func_3(int);
```

There are local and global module-function.

With a struct, it should be possible to call the functions from the main like

```
modul_1.modul_1_func_1();
```

In know that I have to use function pointers within the structure, but I don't know how to initialize them.

I don't want a a dynamic pointer where I have to change the address each time before I use it. I want to have several pointers within the structure — one for each global function.

I already tried this without success:

```
typedef   void (*func_1_temp)(void);
typedef   void (*func_3_temp)(int);

struct {

    func_1_temp func_1;
    func_3_temp func_3;

} HMI = {

func_1 = &modul_1_func_1(),
func_3 = &modul_1_func_3()

};
```

Does anyone know what I have to do that my dreams come true?
I hope to get a clear interface with this approach.

For other ideas I am thankful as well.

Comment: Your untagged struct `HMI` doesn't compile because of multiple syntax errors.  Is fixing that all that's needed in your view?  You're on the right general track if that's what you want to do, though there are problematic details to be resolved.  Whether it's a good idea is a whole separate issue.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using function pointers for module interface, unless you have specific good reasons apart from "it just looks neater". Function pointers break the "who calls this" and "follow this call" tools in practically all IDEs.

Comment: I fail to see what you're gaining with the function pointers. Is this perhaps an XY problem?

Comment: Sorry for the HMI. I used a copy from my code and didn't see it.
The reason why I want to do this is to get a compact, clear und easy to use module interface. If it is also gives me a nice doxygen documentation I am very happy.

Comment: Any suggest for a smarter interface where I don't just put the global functions into the *.h-file?

Answer (score 1):

The name of a function is, at least in this context, directly usable as a
pointer to the function.

mod.h

```
void modul_1_func_1(void);
void modul_1_func_3(int);
granicus% cat mod.c
static int modul_1_func_2(void);
```

mod.c

```
void modul_1_func_1(void) { return; }
int modul_1_func_2(void) { return 1; }
void modul_1_func_3(int x) { modul_1_func_2(); return; }
granicus% cat main.c
#include "mod.h"
typedef   void (*func_1_temp)(void);
typedef   void (*func_3_temp)(int);
```

main.c

```
int main(void) {
    struct {
        func_1_temp func_1;
        func_3_temp func_3;
    } HMI = {
        modul_1_func_1,
        modul_1_func_3,
    };

    HMI.func_1();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling on my system with `gcc -Wall main.c mod.c` gives no errors or warnings.